# Was the Norwegian container house based on a real building?

Tags: realism, the-midnight-sky

In *The Midnight Sky*, the main character finds an abandoned container-like house in the Arctic landscape where they take shelter.

This container has a Norwegian flag and some text on it.

Is it based on a real type of building used in this kind of landscape or in Arctic research stations?

I was surprised that there was not a two layer entrance (airlock), to keep out cold air and snow.

Comment: idk, but I don't see why not - see images of London's [Containerville](https://www.google.com/search?q=containerville&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&sxsrf=ALeKk00An0iRzHaTNPTOGs62D-YqoRS26w:1618729761049&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-y5OjnofwAhXWRhUIHTGXDZ0Q_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1148&bih=1329) offices, or [Container Villa](https://www.google.com/search?q=container+villa&tbm=isch&safe=off&bih=1329&biw=1148&client=safari&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKvd_onofwAhUJw4UKHV3vBg4QrNwCKAF6BQgBEN4B) houses

Comment: Just because something has added value doesn't mean that you therefore _must_ have it. While airlocks are better from an energy-efficiency perspective, they're not particularly _required_ compared to e.g. spaceships or submarines where you very much need that airlock for pressurization/atmospheric reasons. By and large, you'd be better off properly insulating the walls instead of airlocking the door, if you had to pick.